# Generics Object List for RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, generics, android-recyclerview

I currently have

```
public class MyRecycler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

private List<SectionOrRow> mData;

public MyRecycler(List<SectionOrRow> data) {
    mData = data;
}

...

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

...
```

}

and need to pass a list of objects using

```
SectionOrRow.createRow("row x");
```

or

```
SectionOrRow.createSection("section x");
```

however I do not know where or how to construct this list. Adding it so that the code becomes

```
public Adapter(List<SectionOrRow> data) {
    SectionOrRow.createRow("row 1");
    SectionOrRow.createSection("section 1");
    mData = data;
}
```

gives the following error:

> Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Inferring, this sounds like my mData has size is null, as the error occurs on the line that returns the mData size; so obviously adding it inside that class is incorrect. What is the correct way to construct the list?

Edit 1: SectionOrRow class:

```
public class SectionOrRow {

private String row;
private String section;
private boolean isRow;

public static SectionOrRow createRow(String row) {
    SectionOrRow ret = new SectionOrRow();
    ret.row = row;
    ret.isRow = true;
    return ret;
}

public static SectionOrRow createSection(String section) {
    SectionOrRow ret = new SectionOrRow();
    ret.section = section;
    ret.isRow = false;
    return ret;
}

public String getRow() {
    return row;
}

public String getSection() {
    return section;
}

public boolean isRow() {
    return isRow;
}
```

}

Comment: add the code of `SectionOrRow`

Comment: Added! @jignesh

Comment: Show the code you use `MyRecycler` .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: In your static methods I think your making 2 different objects that dont satisfy the properties of the SectionOrRow class. Your Instantiating a new object each time in the method body. Since its a bool you could flip it and set one of the properties to a " " empty string.  ex.                                                    
    'public static      
     SectionOrRow createRow(String row) {
    SectionOrRow ret = new SectionOrRow();
    ret.row = row;
    ret.isRow = true;
       if(ret.isRow = true)
 ret.section= " -";//--something to make it not null.
    return ret;'

Comment: @Talisman show the code from you setup `Adapter`

Comment: Make setter  for each variable like  sectionOrRow.setRow("any row"); same as well for other two variables and after that add this class object in your generic list you have created.

Comment: @Arora I think I'm hung up on how to actually add the class object to the list - the rest of the code is in place.

Comment: send me your code I will do it for you